# Copy stack trace from IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When the program has stopped at a breakpoint, I want to copy the current stack trace (the call stack) and paste it into a text file.

Unfortunately, the current version of IntelliJ Idea does not provide such functionality in the debugger frames window.

Answer (score 11):

You can use:

1. IDEA 2018.1 where "copy stack" action was finally introduced
2. Export threads action from the frames view context menu
3. Thread dump action from the left debugger toolbar

Comment: right click on any frame and "Export threads" -  works.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to add a special watch (the green + in the Variables window of the debugger), either

```
new Exception("debug").getStackTrace()
```

or

```
org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.join(new Exception("debug").getStackTrace(),"\n")
```

It is possible to copy (and paste as text) the value of such watch, and this value is the stack trace.

(You should be able to use String.join() in Java 8 or TextUtils.join(delimiter, array) in Android)